# EDID Emulator with HDMI Matrix and Multiple Monitors

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, hdmi, emulator, edid

I have an HDMI matrix which I use to switch multiple input sources between a couple different monitors (they are the same resolution). One of the input sources is a PC with Windows 10 installed.

Because the monitors are not the same model or even the same brand (one is Asus and one is a Dell), when I switch the PC from one monitor to the other using the HDMI Matrix, the windows jump around and the desktop icons get re-arranged. This seems to be because Windows realizes that one monitor is different than the other and it "disconnects" it briefly so it can change all of the monitor information (for example, changing it from showing up as an "Asus" monitor to a "Dell" monitor).

I have heard about EDID Emulators and I think they might remedy this situation. If I put two EDID emulators on the HDMI ports of each of these monitors, can I somehow trick Windows into thinking they are both the same one? In other words, when I switch with the HDMI matrix, because I'm hiding that one is a dell and one is an Asus (I assume Windows would see whatever brand the EDID emulator is), it will think they are the same and won't automatically disconnect when I switch. Am I understanding this correctly?

Or would I need different hardware to do this?